# Bash shell read names of files from folder and create an output file for each input file with the same name:

Tags: bash, shell

In bash shell I am reading all the files in a folder as follows:

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
 FILES=MyFolder/*
 for f in $FILES
 do
    echo "Started $f file..."
    ./$f > $f_july_15.txt
    echo "Finished $f file..."
 done
```

In line 6 I am trying to save the output of each file in a txt file that contains the name of the input file as follows: `$f_july_15.txt`. I noticed that the txt file does not get created at all, while the `echo` calls and the command `./$f` get executed correctly. I played a little bit moving `$f` inside the name, but I can not get the name of the input file in the output file.
Can anyone please show me why this is happening and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underscore is a valid character in variable names.

Do:

```
./"$f" > "${f}_july_15.txt"
```

Your code was trying to use a variable named `f_july_15`. You need to use braces to delimit the variable name when it's followed by a character that can be part of a variable name.